# Asynctask issue on android version < 4

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have developed an app to support android os 4 and above. I have used an Asynctask to make an web service call during app start up.

Later I have changed my minSdkVersion to 9. To support android 2.3 and above. But the same code throws below error.

**Calling AsyncTask from SplashActivity thread**

> ```
>   mSplashTread = new Thread() {           @Override           public void run() {
>           try {
>               int waited = 0;
>               while (mActive && (waited < mSplashTime)) {
>                   sleep(100);
>                   if (mActive) {
>                       waited += 100;
>                   }
>               }
>           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>               AppUtil.getInstance().logErrorMessage(TAG, e.getMessage());
>           } finally {
>               if (mIsBackPressed) {
>                   finish();
>               } else {
>                   GetMobilePremissionWebservice getMobilePermissionWebservice = new GetMobilePremissionWebservice(
>                           mContext, SplashActivity.this);
>                   getMobilePermissionWebservice.getMobilePermissionInfo();
>               }
>           }           }       };
> ```

**Log:**

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
>   thread that has not called Looper.prepare() at
>   android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:421) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.(AsyncTask.java:421)

I have checked on the web. Someone saying that the Asynctask internally using the Handler. when it tries to access the UI from doInBackgrond(). 
But the same code is working fine in os 4 and above. I don't know what is the issue with Asynctask on Android versions 2.3.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Could you post the code of your AsyncTask implementation?

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: In what thread do you create first asynctask instance? It seems that internal static handler was not created in the UI thread, therefore it throws that exception.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. I think the problem might be I am calling from splashactivity thread. But how the same will be working in android 4.2 samsung devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem is I am calling the Asynctask from a thread.

By using runOnUiThread I am calling Asynctask from an thread is sloves my problem.

```
mSplashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    while (mActive && (waited < mSplashTime)) {
                        sleep(100);
                        if (mActive) {
                            waited += 100;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    AppUtil.getInstance().logErrorMessage(TAG, e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    if (mIsBackPressed) {
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                GetMobilePremissionWebservice getMobilePermissionWebservice = new GetMobilePremissionWebservice(
                                        mContext, SplashActivity.this);
                                getMobilePermissionWebservice
                                        .getMobilePermissionInfo();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

But Still I dont know why the same code working in android version 4.2 Samsung s3.

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating UI on postexecute instead of doInBackground.
Only fetchdata in doInBackground then use that data in postexecute to update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It means you have to call the `AsyncTask.execute(...)` method on the main thread.

While the previous sentence is not technically correct it is 99% of time the intended behavior. After all you use the async task to offload computing *from main thread to background thread*. If you're already on a background thread, you don't need an async task, do you?

Answer (score 0):

Because the proper formate for making service call is as follow. try following formate to make your web service call

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //show progress dialog
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        try 
        {
            postData();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {

        //dismiss progress dialog
    }
}

    public void postData()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread() 
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Looper.prepare(); 
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yourURL");

                try
                {
                    // Your webservice code......

                }
                catch (ClientProtocolException e)
                {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                 e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };
        t.start();  
    } 

}
```

this will solve your error...

Comment: This is wrong.. Do in background itself run our code outside of UI thread. we dont have to create an thread inside of doInBackgground(). I solved my issue. Please find my answer below.